# Read returned XML by function with SimpleXML

Tags: php, function, kohana, simplexml

This is sort of confusing to explain, so thank you ahead of time for bearing with me.

I am using Kohana PHP framework to develop an application. I have a model function that accepts parameters for a search, and should return an XML styled page. I need this to be read by the controller with SimpleXML. Any ideas how to do this?

```
    $o = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    $o .= "<feed>\n";
    $o .= "\t<search_phrase>$q</search_phrase>\n";

    if(isset($entries)){
        uasort($entries, 'compare_weight');

        /**
         * Build the xml data
         */

        foreach($modules as $module){
        $o .= "\t<search_location>$module</search_location>\n";
        }

        foreach($entries as $k=>$entry){
            $o .= "\n\t<entry>\n";
            $o .= "\t\t<title>$entry[title]</title>\n";
            $o .= "\t\t<url>$entry[url]</url>\n";
            $o .= "\t\t<weight>$entry[weight]</weight>\n";
            $o .= "\t\t<module>$entry[module]</module>\n";

            if($entry['owners']){
                foreach($entry['owners'] as $owner){
                    $o .= "\t\t<owners>\n";
                    $o .= "\t\t\t<owner_id>$owner[owner_id]</owner_id>\n";
                    $o .= "\t\t\t<owner_name>$owner[owner_name]</owner_name>\n";
                    $o .= "\t\t\t<profile_link>$owner[profile_link]</profile_link>\n";
                    $o .= "\t\t</owners>\n";
                }
            }

            $o .= "\t</entry>\n";
        }       
    }else{
        $o .= "\t<noresult>true</noresult>\n";
    }

    $o .= "</feed>\n";

    return $o;
```

The controller functions like this... It's the closest I'm able to come to wrapping my head how to do this.

```
    $return= $this->search->search($_GET);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($return);
    die($xml);
```

It returns a blank document with 44 blank lines. Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: I suggest using DOMDocument to construct your XML as it provides a robust API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insted of using the constructor of simpleXML try using the [simplexml_load_string()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return of your $xml feed to:

```
return echo $o;
```